# Is Firebase snapshot scalable?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I'm building a realtime collaborative app. The total document size can be up to 100+ MB, but there is a logical division within the document that can be up to 10+ MB.

The best analogy is something like Photoshop where there are perhaps dozens of layers of images, but each layer can have millions of pixels that need to be synced. Users generally would modify only a part of a single layer in my app. I want to collaboratively edit a document of such size. Firebase has a drawing app, but the scale of it is tiny.

Ideally I'd like to receive events for addition/deletion/update of individual records in a collection rather than getting the whole collection back. In this example, I'd like to be able to receive only the pixels that changed.

Is the only way to do this to create a unique collection for each piece of the document? Or am I doing something wrong or understanding it wrong? Any good architectural pointers/advice?

Thanks,
Brett

Comment: I'm with Jay here. Almost any application can be modeled into Firebase, since it's just a (admittedly awesome) database. How to efficiently map your problem onto that database is a different matter though. It's incredibly broad, depends on knowing all your use-cases and now easily answered in a few paragraphs. If you have a data structure in mind and have a use-case that you find difficult to fit, post back with those specifics and we can probably help further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is pretty open ended and you should really provide some code as to what you have tried and perhaps a Firebase data structure.

That being said, the answer is that yes, it can be done; but there are issues to overcome.

If your requirement is to update collaborators with only the pixels that have changed, that's going to be a challenge if you are storing 10Mb slices of the whole image.

If pixels 5000 and 5001 in slice_0 are changed, you will need to write out that entire 10Mb slice to Firebase (as it's stored in a single node), which would then notify your collaborators via an observe event so then they will download that 10Mb slice (Ouch)

That's pushing around a lot of data because it's not granular enough.

An easier solution is to decompose the data and store the elements, take a string for example; "Hello, World"

```
my_string
  element_00: "H"
  element_01: "e"
  element_02: "l"
  ...
  element_11: "d"
```

With this structure if element_02 changes, it's an easy update for all collaborators. However, you now have millions of nodes storing single pieces of data.

Expanding on that structure, you would need to decide what size slice of data vs performance vs scalability would work for your app:

```
my_string
  element_00
      data: "Hel"
      start: 0
      end: 2
  element_01:
      data: "lo,"
      start: 3
      end: 5
  element_02
      data: " Wo"
      start: 6
      end: 8
  element_03
      data: "old"
      start: 9
      end: 11
```

Now if element_02 changes, it's much more manageable and far fewer nodes to deal with and the node is easily located as each stores 3 values and you know which values they are via start and end.

There are dozens of other structures that would work: For example: eliminate the start and end child nodes and calculate the node name via an equation to get the one you want. For example; node_name = int( pixel_# / 3 ), so character 3 (l) would be element_01 via 3/3 = 01.

We don't know the scope of the app so I would suggest taking a 100Mb file, craft up some code and a Firebase structure and give it a whirl.

You may try slicing into 1Mb slices (so there would be 100 of them) and see how the performance is and adjust from there.

Comment: Thanks Jay. You basically answered my question: Anything that works is acceptable :-) It's just not as clean and simple as I was hoping for.